# Next steps after creating virtualenv (new github project)?

Tags: python, github

I want to write a small Python dummy project:

```
print('Hello world.')
```

... in a file called `hello.py`.

Next: I want to make this a small dummy project at github.

After creating a virtual-env (via PyCharm) I  have these directories:

```
  ./foo
  ./foo/venv
  ./foo/venv/lib
  ./foo/venv/lib/python3.6
  ./foo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
  ./foo/venv/include
  ./foo/venv/bin
```

I want to store my small project in git and upload it to github later.

Are there (official) docs how to start a new project after creating the virtualenv?

Comment: What do you mean by 'how to start a new project'. Do you mean how to create and publish to a repo on github?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe this is what you are looking for:

**How to create a repository in github:**

1. In the upper-right corner of any page, click , and then click New
   repository.
2. In the Owner drop-down, select the account you wish to create the
   repository on.
3. Type a name for your repository, and an optional description.
4. Choose to make the repository either public or private. Public
   repositories are visible to the public, while private repositories
   are only accessible to you, and people you share them with. For more
   information, see "Setting repository visibility."
5. When you're finished, click Create repository.

[Creating a repo](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-new-repository)

**Adding an existing project to a repo:**

1. Open Terminal.
2. Change the current working directory to your local project.
3. Initialize the local directory as a Git repository.

`$ git init`

4. Add the files in your new local repository. This stages them for the
   first commit.

`$ git add .`

5. Adds the files in the local repository and stages them for commit. 
   Commit the files that you've staged in your local repository.

`$ git commit -m "First commit"`

Commits the tracked changes and prepares them to be pushed to a remote repository.

6. In Terminal, add the URL for the remote repository where your local
   repository will be pushed.

`$ git remote add origin remote "repositoryURLgoesHere"`
*Sets the new remote*

`$ git remote -v`
*Verifies the new remote URL*

[Adding a project to the repo](https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line)